# Listing object from AWS S3 in Angular 2

Tags: angular, amazon-web-services, listobject

The issue is that bucketObject is NOT getting populated from response of AWS S3 service of listObject API.

May be i am doing something wrong. Could you please guide me?

Below is my code

```
bucketObject = [];

listBucketFromS3()
{

        let AWSService = (<any>window).AWS;

        AWSService.config.accessKeyId  = '<my access key>';

        AWSService.config.secretAccessKey  = '<my secret key>';

        AWSService.config.region = '<my region>';

        let bucket =  new AWSService.S3({params: {Bucket: '<my bucket>'}});


        bucket.listObjects(function(error,res){

            console.log('error:',error);

            console.log(res);

            this.bucketObject = res.Contents;


        });  

}
```

Please let me know if you need any other information

Thanks in Advance!!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, i got the answer

We need to use below code....

private bucketObject;

bucket.listObjects(function(error,res){

```
        let that = this;

        console.log('error:',error);

        console.log(res);

        that.bucketObject = res.Contents;


    });
```

I am not sure the logic but this will work :D